# C++ does not insert numbers/digits into the vector as desired

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm writing code where my program needs to separate variables and constants from given equation. This is the initial idea I came up with:

```
std::string eq = argv[1];               // eg: y=2x+5
std::vector <char> variables;
std::vector <int> constants;

for(int i = 0; i < eq.size(); i++) {
  if(isalpha(eq[i]) && eq[i] != 'c') {
  variables.push_back(eq[i]);
  }
}

for(int i = 0; i < eq.size(); i++) {
  if(isdigit(eq[i])) {
  constants.push_back(eq[i]);
  }
}

for(auto j: constants) {
  std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

Everything is fine until where the constants from the equation are separated and stored in the vector `constants`. Whenever the code is executed and contents of the vector `constants` is checked, totally different and in-correct values are returned. Here's an example:

Equation: y=2x+5

Required output (from the vector `constants`) = 2, 5

Output generated by the program               = 50, 53

Any idea where I am going wrong? No error(s) are reported during compilation.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal example of the code which is causing trouble?

Comment: You are aware that a string doesn't hold the numbers, but a character representation of the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ASCII character set, the characters `'0'` through `'9'` have numeric values of `48` through to `57`.  Converting a `char` to an `int` gives the numeric value.  For example, the char with value `'4'` will have a numeric value of `52`.   That explains your values "like 50, 53 or 52".

To convert a digit to the value you expect (`'0'` to `0`, .... `'9'` to `9`) subtract `'0'`.   For example;

```
 char x = '5';
 int n = x;
 int v = x - '0';
 std::cout << "'" << v << "' has the numeric value " << n << '\n';
```

Note that different (non-ASCII) character sets will give different numeric values.   But this type of conversion works for all standard character sets.

Comment: Yes! This worked.
Thanks a lot Peter. :)

Comment: Need to emphasize that this conversion (`x - '0'`) is required to work for all character sets. The ASCII stuff is really just a distraction.

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind. :) @PeteBecker

Comment: @OK - edited reply to address that.   The reason for mentioning ASCII is that the question described digits having values of "50,53, or 52", which is consistent with ASCII, not with other character sets.   But, yes, the conversion `x-'0'` works for all standardised character sets.